# How to pick from multiple lists randomly to fill DFcolumns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

I want to fill a Pandas DataFrame with 3 columns and 20 rows based on random values from the 3 lists below. I cant quite figure out what I am doing wrong.  Any suggestions?

```
import random
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


tests= ['TestA', 'TestB', 'TestC', 'TestD']
projects = ['AK', 'AA', 'JH', 'WM']
number = [10, 100, 200, 1000, 2000]

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1,21):
    df = df.append(
    {'TEST': random.choice(tests),
    'PROJ': random.choice(projects),
    'NUMBER': random.choice(number)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.random.choice`:

```
tests= ['TestA', 'TestB', 'TestC', 'TestD']
projects = ['AK', 'AA', 'JH', 'WM']
number = [10, 100, 200, 1000, 2000]

num_rows = 20

# for repeatability, drop in actual code
np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TEST': np.random.choice(tests, size=num_rows),
    'PROJ': np.random.choice(projects, size=num_rows),
    'NUMBER': np.random.choice(number, size=num_rows)
})
```

Output:

```
     TEST PROJ  NUMBER
0   TestB   JH     100
1   TestD   AA     100
2   TestA   JH     100
3   TestA   AK     100
4   TestD   WM      10
5   TestB   AK    2000
6   TestD   JH     100
7   TestB   AK      10
8   TestD   AA      10
9   TestA   JH    1000
10  TestA   JH     200
11  TestB   AK     100
12  TestA   WM      10
13  TestD   WM    1000
14  TestB   AA     100
15  TestA   AA     100
16  TestC   WM    1000
17  TestB   JH    2000
18  TestC   AK      10
19  TestA   JH     100
```

Answer (score 2):

ignore index when appending...

```
for i in range(1,21):
    df = df.append(
    {'TEST': random.choice(tests),
    'PROJ': random.choice(projects),
    'NUMBER': random.choice(number)},
    ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to @quang-hoang's version except it's using `random.choices`:

```
import random
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


tests= ['TestA', 'TestB', 'TestC', 'TestD']
projects = ['AK', 'AA', 'JH', 'WM']
number = [10, 100, 200, 1000, 2000]

df = pd.DataFrame()

## add a random.seed if you want reproducibility

_t = random.choices(tests,k=20)
_p = random.choices(projects,k=20)
_n = random.choices(number,k=20)

pd.DataFrame({'Test':_t,'Project':_p,'Number':_n})
```